# I'm developing a hangman guessing algorithm and wanted a clear explanation of something I saw

Tags: algorithm

So far in my algorithm I have filtered the following to deduce the correct words

- if i guess a letter and it isn't there, filter all words with that letter
- if i guess a letter and it is there, filter any words without that letter in that specific placement
- filter out words that don't match the length of the word being guessed

What I wanted clarification on, was how and if peeking into the next letter would help improve my algorithm, (I saw this in another post and wasn't sure how this would help improve the algorithm, if at all)

It was suggested that you could guess letters based on the resultant word bank after the filter went through I quote:

> "you might be able to run a look-ahead. If we choose "A" at this level what options does that present for the next level? This is an O(x^n) algorithm, obviously you can't go too far down that path."

Can someone help explain to me how this would be implemented and how it would improve my code?

Comment: If you decide on some guess, you can play through your rules and wordset to get an idea how many possible candidates will be thrown away in average. This will lower your number of guesses needed on average (at least in a non-adversary setting). It's more or less linked to: how much information will i gain with this guess vs. the other (which might be very different compared to: maximizing the probability in finishing the game with this guess). Maybe search for some *mastermind* resources, a slightly different game, but with many nice papers mentioning many different views on deduction games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symbol sequences are not random in any natural language.  A simple case is that in English "Q" is almost always followed by "U".  Thus, when you have a correct letter, you can now look through all the remaining words to see what letters most frequently follow (or just appear with) the one(s) you know already.  Use the *new* letter frequencies to make your next guess.